# python script for RaspberryPi to connect wifi automatically

Tags: python, wifi, raspberry-pi

I want to operate a WiFi dongle with RaspberryPi, (it's like a CPU without built-in WiFi). I need to write a python script which automatically scan for WiFi networks and a connection need to be automatically established with known SSID and password.

This mean that I need to provide the password for the WiFi network from a file, and the
remaining thing is to do the scanning and connecting automatically.

I read a file from the Web which contains WiFi SSID name and password.

I need to write a script which scan and list current networds and match it to the SSID from the file and further to automatically create the connection to this known network.

RaspberryPi OS: Rasbian

Comment: Your question doesn't seem to make sense somehow. You want to get the wifi details from the web and then use them to connect to the wifi? How are you supposed to do that without an internet connection?

Comment: I am not sure what you need help with, are you looking for a Raspberry script which can automatically connect to a network if it turns up from scanning the current WiFi-environment? And do you want to write the script or do you want to find a module which does this for you?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Thank you all for your answers i made simple solution like below

```
def wifiscan():

   allSSID = Cell.all('wlan0')
   print allSSID # prints all available WIFI SSIDs
   myssid= 'Cell(ssid=vivekHome)' # vivekHome is my wifi name

   for i in range(len(allSSID )):
        if str(allSSID [i]) == myssid:
                a = i
                myssidA = allSSID [a]
                print b
                break
        else:
                print "getout"

   # Creating Scheme with my SSID.
   myssid= Scheme.for_cell('wlan0', 'home', myssidA, 'vivek1234') # vive1234 is the password to my wifi myssidA is the wifi name 

   print myssid
   myssid.save()
   myssid.activate()

wifiscan()
```

Comment: can you please put your all code for connecting wifi because this code is giving me an error for  " myssidA "

Comment: I recommend NOT to put the password out in the open. Hopefully it is not the actual password.

Answer (score 20):

[wifi](https://wifi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) is a python library for scanning and connecting to wifi networks on linux.  You can use it to scan and connect to wireless networks.

It doesn't have any built-in support for connecting automatically to a network, but you could easily write a script to do that.  Here's an example of a basic idea for how to do this.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from __future__ import print_function

from wifi import Cell, Scheme

# get all cells from the air
ssids = [cell.ssid for cell in Cell.all('wlan0')]

schemes = list(Scheme.all())

for scheme in schemes:
    ssid = scheme.options.get('wpa-ssid', scheme.options.get('wireless-essid'))
    if ssid in ssids:
        print('Connecting to %s' % ssid)
        scheme.activate()
        break
```

I just wrote it and it seems to work.  Just so you know, I wrote the wifi library.  If you want me to add this feature to that library, I could.

Comment: Hey @rockymeza, I think an autoconnect feature could be awesome and would be very helpful for raspberry pi users in particular!

Comment: @rockymeza I dont understand how to use it? I don't need generate a password? because when I use you code my wifi still didn't connect. Thankyou

Comment: Do you have anything in the output of `schemes = list(Scheme.all())`? If not, it is because first you must create schemes. Please see http://wifi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/scanning.html#connecting-to-a-network for more information.

Comment: Thanks for creating this; I couldn't get it to work on my pi3s as it seems like the Schemes just add iface wlan0-<SSIDname> to the /etc/network/interfaces file, and there is no mapping or anything to tell it that ifup wlan0-<SSIDname> is associated with 'wlan0';  I ended up doing a monkey patch so that it will use the /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf file instead; see my patch below

Answer (score 1):

This is a monkey patch of rockymeza's answer above, so that the Scheme will use the /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf file instead of the /etc/network/interfaces file. I couldn't get his Scheme class to work on my pi3s as it seems like the Schemes just adds iface wlan0-SSIDname for each network to the /etc/network/interfaces file, and there is no mapping or anything to tell it that ifup wlan0-SSIDname is associated with 'wlan0'.

```
import re
from wifi import Cell, Scheme
import wifi.subprocess_compat as subprocess
from wifi.utils import ensure_file_exists

class SchemeWPA(Scheme):

    interfaces = "/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf"

    def __init__(self, interface, name, options=None):
        self.interface = interface
        self.name = name
        self.options = options or {} 

    def __str__(self):
        """
        Returns the representation of a scheme that you would need
        in the /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf file.
        """

        options = ''.join("\n    {k}=\"{v}\"".format(k=k, v=v) for k, v in self.options.items())
        return "network={" + options + '\n}\n'

    def __repr__(self):
            return 'Scheme(interface={interface!r}, name={name!r}, options={options!r}'.format(**vars(self))
    def save(self):
        """
        Writes the configuration to the :attr:`interfaces` file.
        """
        if not self.find(self.interface, self.name):
            with open(self.interfaces, 'a') as f:
                f.write('\n')
                f.write(str(self))        

    @classmethod
    def all(cls):
        """
        Returns an generator of saved schemes.
        """
        ensure_file_exists(cls.interfaces)
        with open(cls.interfaces, 'r') as f:
            return extract_schemes(f.read(), scheme_class=cls) 
    def activate(self):
        """
        Connects to the network as configured in this scheme.
        """

        subprocess.check_output(['/sbin/ifdown', self.interface], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
        ifup_output = subprocess.check_output(['/sbin/ifup', self.interface] , stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
        ifup_output = ifup_output.decode('utf-8')

        return self.parse_ifup_output(ifup_output)
    def delete(self):
        """
        Deletes the configuration from the /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf file.
        """
        content = ''
        with open(self.interfaces, 'r') as f:
            lines=f.read().splitlines()
            while lines:
                line=lines.pop(0)

                if line.startswith('#') or not line:
                    content+=line+"\n"
                    continue

                match = scheme_re.match(line)
                if match:
                    options = {}
                    ssid=None
                    content2=line+"\n"
                    while lines and lines[0].startswith(' '):
                        line=lines.pop(0)
                        content2+=line+"\n"
                        key, value = re.sub(r'\s{2,}', ' ', line.strip()).split('=', 1)
                        #remove any surrounding quotes on value
                        if value.startswith('"') and value.endswith('"'):
                            value = value[1:-1]
                        #store key, value
                        options[key] = value
                        #check for ssid (scheme name)
                        if key=="ssid":
                            ssid=value
                    #get closing brace        
                    line=lines.pop(0)
                    content2+=line+"\n"

                    #exit if the ssid was not found so just add to content
                    if not ssid:
                        content+=content2
                        continue
                    #if this isn't the ssid then just add to content
                    if ssid!=self.name:
                        content+=content2

                else:
                    #no match so add content
                    content+=line+"\n"
                    continue

        #Write the new content
        with open(self.interfaces, 'w') as f:
            f.write(content)    

scheme_re = re.compile(r'network={\s?')


#override extract schemes
def extract_schemes(interfaces, scheme_class=SchemeWPA):
    lines = interfaces.splitlines()
    while lines:
        line = lines.pop(0)
        if line.startswith('#') or not line:
            continue

        match = scheme_re.match(line)
        if match:
            options = {}
            interface="wlan0"
            ssid=None

            while lines and lines[0].startswith(' '):
                key, value = re.sub(r'\s{2,}', ' ', lines.pop(0).strip()).split('=', 1)
                #remove any surrounding quotes on value
                if value.startswith('"') and value.endswith('"'):
                    value = value[1:-1]
                #store key, value
                options[key] = value
                #check for ssid (scheme name)
                if key=="ssid":
                    ssid=value

            #exit if the ssid was not found
            if ssid is None:
                continue
            #create a new class with this info
            scheme = scheme_class(interface, ssid, options)

            yield scheme
```

To create the scheme, just do this:

```
scheme=SchemeWPA('wlan0',cell.ssid,{"ssid":cell.ssid,"psk":"yourpassword"})
```

Your /etc/network/interfaces file should look like this, or similar:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'
# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet manual

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

iface default inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the natively available network manager cli package (nmcli):

```
import subprocess

def what_wifi():
    process = subprocess.run(['nmcli', '-t', '-f', 'ACTIVE,SSID', 'dev', 'wifi'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    if process.returncode == 0:
        return process.stdout.decode('utf-8').strip().split(':')[1]
    else:
        return ''

def is_connected_to(ssid: str):
    return what_wifi() == ssid

def scan_wifi():
    process = subprocess.run(['nmcli', '-t', '-f', 'SSID,SECURITY,SIGNAL', 'dev', 'wifi'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    if process.returncode == 0:
        return process.stdout.decode('utf-8').strip().split('\n')
    else:
        return []
        
def is_wifi_available(ssid: str):
    return ssid in [x.split(':')[0] for x in scan_wifi()]

def connect_to(ssid: str, password: str):
    if not is_wifi_available(ssid):
        return False
    subprocess.call(['nmcli', 'd', 'wifi', 'connect', ssid, 'password', password])
    return is_connected_to(ssid)

def connect_to_saved(ssid: str):
    if not is_wifi_available(ssid):
        return False
    subprocess.call(['nmcli', 'c', 'up', ssid])
    return is_connected_to(ssid)
```

Connect to a saved network:

```
connect_to_saved('my_wifi')
```

Otherwise, connect to a network with ssid and password:

```
connect_to('my_wifi', 'my_password')
```