# Connecting to Wifi via python script - for Raspberry Pi3

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, wifi

**Hello, I'm currently developing in Pyqt5 for raspberry Pi, and I need to make the Wifi connection inside my ui_window**

The problem is, there are some libraries, but with all of them, at least I get 2 errors.
like:
If I do try this one: https://github.com/emlid/pywificontrol
I get a message saying:

> File "/home/pi/Desktop/pywificontrol-master/wificontrol/**init**.py", line 1, in 
>       from wificontrol import WiFiControl
>   ImportError: cannot import name 'WiFiControl'

If I do try this one: https://pypi.org/project/python-wifi/

> I get a message saying:
>     File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pythonwifi/iwlibs.py", line 1228, in **init**
>   TypeError: cannot use a str to initialize an array with typecode 'c

I did try some other libraries, but all of them without success. Most of them are unmaintained.

So, guys, someone that has already worked with something similar.. could u give me some advice? I'm really stuck in this problem as I must let the user of the software chooses which Wifi connection he wants to use. He will be using a touch lcd display, and need to choose the connection.

Comment: Have you tried `pip install wifi`? There's usage examples here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20470626/python-script-for-raspberrypi-to-connect-wifi-automatically

Comment: Sorry for the late late reply.
I need to use pip3 as I'm currently using Python3.
So, I can't use the pip install wifi.
@rassar

Comment: @Marco just use `pip3 install wifi` then... in any event, I tried this pip and it works for scanning wifi but not for connecting to wifi, even on sudo... seems it uses `ifdown` and rpi uses `ifconfig`

Answer (score 1):

To do that, you can use the os.system() function and connect to the network by execute this bash command:

$ iwconfig wlan0 essid name key password

Replace wlan0 n'y tour network interface, name by the network’s name and password by the actual password

So the python code is:

```
import os
interface = 'wlan0'
name = ‘Wifi’
password = ‘password’
os.system('iwconfig ' + interface + ' essid ' + name + ' key ' + password)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install WiFi for python 3 you can write this command:

```
sudo python3 -m pip install wifi
```

it works perfectly for my raspberry pi3

Comment: Were you able to use this pip to actually connect to wifi? I only got it to work for scanning, when I tried connecting (I ran it as root btw) it failed.

Comment: Did you try 
sudo iwlist wlan0 scan?

Comment: yes, I only got it to work for scanning, when I tried connecting (I ran it as root btw) it failed

Comment: According to the docs, this is supposed to be a command, but I can't find it when I try to run it. I can import it as a module. I can't use `python3 -m wifi` and the docs provide ways to use it as a command, but no reference to use it as a library from Python code. Do you have anything about using it from within Python code?